# Regex values between brackets

Tags: php, html, regex, arrays, preg-match-all

I want to receive all values between brackets into an array, but I don't get it working.

Input:

```
Hello, My name is {NAMES.ID1} and I am {USER.age} and I do {HOBBY.NAME}.
```

Ouput:

```
array (
[0] (
[category] > "NAMES";
[value] > "ID1";
)
[1] (
[category] > "USER";
[value] > "age";
)
[2] (
[category] > "HOBBY";
[value] > "NAME";
)
)
```

I made this, but it is not working properly. Can somebody help me out please?

```
/(\{([^\]]*)\.([^\]]*)\})/i
```

http://regex101.com/r/fT2lW0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you typed braces instead of brackets...

```
/(\{([^}]*)\.([^}]*)\})/gi
```

Alternatively you could probably just use

```
/{(.*?)}/gi
```